# ffmpeg не сохраняет обрезанное видео

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

FFMpeg при попытке установить обрезанной ролик сообщает `Output file is empty` или `codec frame size is not set`. Но так не со всеми видео роликами, некоторые устанавливаются корректно

Перед запуском ffmpeg выполняется получение urls

`yt-dlp-g “url”`

Это команда выдают два url. Первый на видос, второй на аудио.

Ffmpeg команда

`ffmpeg -ss 00:15:53 -i “url1” -ss 00:15:53 -i “url2” -t 00:00:22 -c copy file.mp4`

Когда менял кодек на `-c:a aac` аудио успешно сохранялось

В конце пишет
`encoded 0 frames`

Comment: а чего сразу на обрезать еще при скачивании ? как вариант: `yt-dlp --download-sections "*15:53-16:15" URL`

Comment: 0__0, спасибо. Я не знал что так можно